# Bessel's Correction Confusion: Random Variable is derived but sample from Random Variable is used in practice

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Let $X$ be the set of random variables $X=\{X_{1},X_{2}, \dots,X_{N}\}$ and random variable $X_{i}$ be i.i.d from $X_{j}$ for $i\neq j$.

From  $E[\text{var}(X)]=E\left[ \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N (X_{i}-\bar{X})^2 \right]$ you can eventually reach $E[\text{var(X)}]=\frac{{N-1}}{N}\text{var}(X_{i})$ using the properties of expectation and the definition of i.i.d.

Isolating $\text{var}(X_{i})$ implies:
$$
\text{var}(X_{i})=\frac{N}{N-1}E[\text{var}(X)]
$$.

where $\text{var}(X_{i})=\sum_{j=1}^M (X_{i,j}-E[X_{i}])$, $M$ is the number of samples for the $i$th random variable (or all random variables since they all have the same distribution).

By definition of $E[\text{var}(X)]$:

$$
\text{var}(X_{i})=\frac{N}{N-1}E\left[ \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N (X_{i}-\bar{X})^2 \right]
$$
$$
= \frac{1}{N-1}E\left[ \sum_{i=1}^N (X_{i}-\bar{X})^2 \right]
$$

, which is apparently the definition of unbiased variance for a random variable $X_{i}$.

This does not make sense to me because I should expect that the variance for $X_{i}$ to be defined in terms of average of the squares in which each square is the deviation between the sample (i.e. $X_{i, j}$ or equivalently, sample $j$ from random variable $X_{i}$) and the average sample in $X_{i}$ but that's not what what was derived. What was derived was the average square deviation between a particular *random variable* (i.e. $X_{i}$) and the average between the *random variables*.

I understand that $\bar{X}=E[X_{i}]$ because random variable $X_{i}$ has an identical distribution to $X_{j}$, but the type of the sample being drawn is the problem for me.

**My question is why is it mathematically safe to imply**:

$$
\text{var}(X_{i})=\frac{1}{N-1}E\left[\sum_{i=1}^N (X_{i}-\bar{X})^2\right] \implies \text{var}(X_{i})=\frac{1}{M-1}E\left[\sum_{j=1}^M (X_{i,j}-E[X_{i}])^2\right]
$$

It seems like everyone uses the latter in practice, yet what is derived is actually the former.

Comment: There really is no difference between the two statements, it is just that in one of them you call the random variables $X_1, \dots, X_N$, while in the other one you call them $X_{i, 1}, \dots, X_{i, M}$ for some fixed $i$. However, the last statement seems to be missing an expectation. Furthermore, it seems that you wrote $\mathbb E(X)$ instead of $\bar X$ in the beginning and middle, even though those two are not the same (one is the expectation, a number, while the other is the empirical average, a random variable). Finally, the notation for $X$ is not quite clear. Is it a set or a sum?

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch You're very right. I need to make the notation more consistent, and yes I forgot to include the expectation for the last statement. I'll make the edits. And I meant $X$ to be a set: $\{X_1, X_2, ..., X_N\} \in X$ and $X \ne X_1 + X_2 + ... + X_N$.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Also, can you expound on what you mean by the difference between $\mathbb{E}(X)$ and $\bar{X}$ because I thought these two notations refer to the same thing: the weighted sum of random variables (not weighted sum of all possible values in a single random variable).

Comment: Darryl, $\mathbb E(Y)$ is the expectation of $Y$, it is a number and also a property of the distribution of $Y$. I am not sure what you mean by $\bar Y$, but as I see it, it means the empirical average, that is, $\frac{Y_1+\dots+Y_n}n$ where $Y_1,…Y_n$ are independent copies of $Y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundamentally, your confusion stems from not properly making a distinction between parameters (more specifically, moments) of a probability distribution, and *estimators* of those parameters.  This becomes especially apparent in your use of notation.

When we talk about the mean or variance of a probability distribution, we aren't speaking about properties of some random sample drawn from that distribution.  For instance, if I say $X$ has a normal distribution with mean $\mu = 1$ and variance $\sigma^2 = 4$, that is literally defining how $X$ is distributed:  $$f_X(x) = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-(x-1)^2/8}, \quad x \in \mathbb R.$$  Or in the case where the distribution is not explicitly parametrized by mean and variance, e.g., $Y$ has a binomial distribution with parameters $n = 7$ and $p = 1/3$, that means
$$\Pr[Y = y] = \binom{7}{y} (1/3)^y (2/3)^{7-y}, \quad y \in \{0, 1, \ldots, 7\}$$ and we can use this to calculate the corresponding moments:  $$\operatorname{E}[Y] = np = \frac{7}{3}, \quad \operatorname{Var}[Y] = np(1-p) = \frac{14}{9}.$$  These are *parameters*:  fixed properties that characterize the distribution in question.

The purpose of statistical inference is to *infer*--specifically through the observation of data that presumably obeys one or more probability distributions--the value of the parameters that specify their behavior.  If we know what the parameters are, there is no need for such inference, so in statistical practice, we are interested in the case where the parameter is fixed but *unknown* to us, and the only way we have access to the parameter(s) of interest is through such observation.

The simplest (nontrivial) case of inference is when the observations arise from simple random sampling, in which we see independent and identically distributed realizations of some random variable, say
$$x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$$
where each $x_i$ is some outcome of an underlying probability distribution; we call this a *sample*, and $n$ is the sample size.

We can use the sample to compute *statistics*: functions of one or more random variables whose calculation does not depend on any unknown parameters.  For instance, we can calculate the sample maximum of
$(17, 2, 11, -5, 31, 4)$, which is $31$.  Or we can calculate the sample mean, which is $10$.  There are infinitely many statistics we can calculate, so long as we can calculate them from information that is available to us, either from the sample itself and/or any known parameters.

An *estimator* is a statistic that estimates one or more parameters or functions of such parameters.  Not all statistics are estimators; e.g., the identity statistic is the sample itself, and it estimates nothing.  Estimators are the connection between the data we observe and the parameters that we wish to know.  However, estimators are random variables, and as a result, the observed value of an estimator will change from one sample to the next.  Because of this, estimators have what is called a *sampling distribution*, and we can calculate moments of that distribution.

For instance, the sample mean is the statistic
$$\bar X = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i,$$
where the sample is a vector-valued random variable $(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$.  If the $X_i$ are iid and have common mean $\mu$, then $\operatorname{E}[X] = \mu$ and by linearity of expectation, the expectation of the sample mean is
$$\operatorname{E}[\bar X] = \operatorname{E}\left[\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right] = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{E}[X_i] = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \mu = \frac{1}{n} \cdot n \mu = \mu.$$  But $\bar X$ does not, in general, have the same distribution as each of the $X_i$.  In the earlier example where $X \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu = 1, \sigma^2 = 4)$, for a sample of size $n = 100$, the sampling distribution of the sample mean is $$\bar X \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu_{\bar X} = 1, \sigma^2_{\bar X} = 0.04).$$  The variance of the sample mean is a parameter $\sigma^2_{\bar X}$ that characterizes the variance of the sampling distribution, and is not to be confused with the *sample variance*, which as we have already implied, is a statistic, not a parameter.

The unbiased estimator (Bessel's correction) of the sample variance is
$$S^2 = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar X)^2,$$
where $\bar X$ is the sample mean defined earlier.  The nature of the correction is, as you pointed out, due to the fact that
$$\operatorname{E}[S^2] = \operatorname{Var}[X_i].$$  But you need to be careful about what the RHS actually is.  The RHS is not a statistic; it is a *parameter*.  Again, in the example where $X$ is normally distributed, $\operatorname{Var}[X_i] = \sigma^2 = 4$.  It's not something that has a numerical value unless you know the actual value of the parameter.  On the LHS, $S^2$ is an estimator; the quantity it estimates is the variance of $X$, through the sample $(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$, because if we observe the sample, we can use it to calculate $S^2$.  The correction factor is there because it makes the resulting estimator *unbiased*, in the sense that the average of many sample variances calculated from many different samples will tend to approach the true variance.

With all of this in mind, we can immediately see why it is unnecessary (and incorrect) to characterize the moments of individual observations $X_i$ in terms of some underlying subsample, e.g.
$$\operatorname{Var}[X_i] \overset{?}{=} \frac{1}{m} \sum_{j=1}^m (X_{ij} - \bar X_i)^2,$$ because the $X_i$ are observations, directly realized from the probability distribution of interest, and are not themselves estimates, because this entire discussion has been about simple random sampling.  If you were interested in cluster sampling, a hierarchical probability model, or something else of that nature, then yes, we could specify such a data structure, but this is not the case.

Comment: I like your definitions of a statistic and an estimator 
with your examples; they're very clear. Why is $\text{Var}[X_i]$ considered to be the unbiased estimator? Is it just by definition of expectation in $E[X_i^2] - E[X_i]^2$? Is expectation always considered to be the population mean $\mu$? If so, then it would make sense that $\text{Var}[X_i]=\sigma^2$, where $\sigma^2$ is the parameter, not a statistic as you say.

Comment: @DarrylBailey The term $\operatorname{Var}(X_i)$ is a property of the distribution of $X_i$. It is always equal to $\mathbb E(X_i^2) - \mathbb E(X_i)^2$, this follows fairly straightforwardly from the definition, which is $$\operatorname{Var}(X_i)=\mathbb E((X_i - \mathbb E(X_i))^2).$$ Sometimes the variance is denoted by $\sigma^2$. Finally, the variance is not an estimator if it depends on the distribution you choose within your statistical model, as is the case for many often-used statistical models.(By statistical model I mean a set of probability distributions, feel free to ask for a ref)

Comment: @DarrylBailey $\operatorname{Var}[X_i]$ is not an estimator.  I stated that this is a parameter.  It is the variance of the random variable $X_i$ that follows some probability distribution; as such, it is fixed.  $X_i$ may vary from one observation to the next, but $\operatorname{Var}[X_i]$ is a fixed property of the probability distribution that $X_i$ follows.

Comment: Right, $\text{Var}[X_i]$ is a parameter, understood. This clears all doubts. Thank you so much!